# Strategies for dealing with constantly changing requirements for MySQL schemas?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate EntityManager and Hibernate Annotations for ORM in a very early stage project. The project needs to launch soon, but the specs are changing constantly and I am concerned that the system will be launched and live data will be collected, and then the specs will change again and I will be in a situation where I need to change the database schema.

How can I set things up in order to minimize the impact of this? Are there any open source projects that deal with this kind of migration? Can Hibernate do this automatically (without wiping the database)?

Your advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's more a functional or organizational problem than a technical one. No tool will automatically guess how to migrate data from one schema to another one. You'd better learn how to write stored procedure in order to migrate your data.

You'll probably need to disable constraints, create temporary table and columns, copy lots of data, and then delete the temporary tables and columns and re-enable constraints to have migrate your data.

Once in maintenance mode, every new feature that modifies the schema should also come with the script allowing to migrate from the current schema and data in production to the new one.

Answer (score 1):

No system can possibly create datamigration scripts automatically from just the original and the final schema. There just isn't enough information.

Consider for example a new column. Should it just contain the default value? Or a value calculated from other fields/tables.

There is a good book about refactoring databases: [http://www.amazon.com/Refactoring-Databases-Evolutionary-Addison-Wesley-Signature/dp/0321774515/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1300140045&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321774515)

But there is little to no tool support for this kind of stuff.

I think the best thing you can do in advance:

- Don't let anybody access the database but your application
- If something else absolutely must access the db directly, give it a separate set of view specially for that purpose. This allows you to change your table structure by keeping at least the structure of what other systems see.
- Have tons of tests. I just posted an article wich (with the upcoming 2nd and 3rd part) might help a little with this: http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2011/03/13/testing-databases-with-junit-and-hibernate-part-1-one-to-rule-them/

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate can update the database entity model with data in the database. So do that and write migration code in java which sets or removes data relationships.

This works, and we have done it multiple times. But of course, try to follow a flexible development process; make what you know for sure first, then reevaluate the requirements - scrum etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I would recommend a [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) database. I don't have much experience with such kind of databases so I can't recommend any current implementation so you may want to check [this](http://nosql-database.org/) too.